# JAVA: Sort ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> on multiple columns

Tags: java, sorting, matrix, arraylist, multiple-columns

First, I did do my homework searching before posting here. My requirement seems to be slightly different compared to questions posted out there.

I have a matrix like `ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>` in the following form

```
| id1 | id2 | score |
|-----|-----|-------|
| 1   | 3   | 95%   |
| 1   | 2   | 100%  |
| 1   | 4   | 85%   |
| 1   | 5   | 95%   |
| 2   | 10  | 80%   |
| 2   | 15  | 99%   |
```

I want to sort the matrix column-wise (first using score, then the id1). I already have the id1 in a sorted manner. That means I also need to sort all records with the same id1 first by using score, second by the id2. The reason for doing this is to create a ranking of the id2 in each id1. The result for the above example would be:

```
| q_id | d_id | rank | score |
|------|------|------|-------|
| 1    | 2    | 1    | 100%  |
| 1    | 3    | 2    | 95%   |
| 1    | 5    | 3    | 95%   |
| 1    | 4    | 4    | 85%   |
| 2    | 15   | 1    | 99%   |
| 2    | 10   | 2    | 80%   |
```

How can I achieve this in Java using some built-in methods of collections?

Comment: Why not using the `Table` type from the [Guava Collections](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/)?

Comment: can you please elaborate on what you wanna achieve ?

Comment: You want a variation of bucket sort / radix sort. First bucket is id1, second bucket is id2.

Answer (score 1):

Create an Object that includes all columns/fields of your each ArrayList row. Then make use of Comparator interface and use Collections.sort().

You can check out http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort%28java.util.List,%20java.util.Comparator%29

Comment: Can you be more elaborate on this?

Comment: I can sort using one column. Whenever I sort using the second column, would not it mess the first sortedness nature? Or is it intelligent enough to let the first sorted result in its form and then sort accordingly using the second key?

Comment: Jim has answered what I was trying to say :)

Answer (score 1):

A proper OO solution would be to declare this as

```
class Bucket {
    int val1;
    int val2;
    int percent;
}

List<Bucket> myList = ...
```

and provide a `Comparator` that orders elements the way you want

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you're describing is in fact a matrix. It looks to me like an array of triplets.

Consider creating a wrapper class for each 'row' of your matrix:

```
class Triplet implements Comparable<Triplet> {
    private int id1;
    private int id2;
    private int score;

    // getters / setters here

    @Override
    int compareTo(Triplet that) {
        // if I understood correctly, you want to sort by score, then id1, then id2.
        int result = this.score - that.getScore();
        if (result == 0) {
            result = this.id1 - that.getId1();
            if (result == 0) {
                result = this.id2 - that.getId2();
            }
        }

        return result;
    }
}
```

Then represent your 'Matrix' as `ArrayList<Triplet>` and just sort as you normally would.

Answer (score 0):

First off, you're better holding your data in a Plain Old Java Object (POJO) rather than a List of Lists of Integers.

From your example, it seems as though your data has three elements: two ids and a score. A POJO might be like this:

```
public class Record() {
    private int id1;
    private int id2;
    private double score; // percent, so double from 0.0 to 1.0

    public Record(int id1, int id2, double score) {
        this.id1=id1;
        this.id2=id2;
        this.score=score;
    }
    // getters and setters
}
```

Then instead of your complicated sub-lists, you'd just have a `List<Record>`.

From what I understand of your question, you want to first sort by id1, then by id2. Is that right? This looks like it calls for [radix sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radix_sort) (link is to Wikipedia).

The psuedo code would be this:

1. Loop through each record and sort them into "buckets" by `id1`. Each "bucket" can be a `List<Record>`, and should contain all `Record` objects with the same id1 in no particular order.
2. Loop through each bucket and sort by `id2`.
3. Group all of your buckets back together, preserving order.

You'll want to update the `Record` object with methods like `public int compareId1(Record other)` and `public int compareId2(Record other)` in order to implement this efficiently and cleanly.